# MTG Cards that interact with each other by name

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

So I know that [Bogbrew Witch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bogbrew%20Witch), [Festering Newt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Festering%20Newt) and [Bubbling Cauldron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bubbling%20Cauldron) all name each other in their rules text and I was wondering if there are any other cards that do this as well. How can I find more cards like that? (A list would certainly be useful, but how to find them would be even more useful.)

Comment: This is basically asking for a list of cards that reference other cards by name. I don't see how such a list could be useful to anyone.

Comment: I just would like to know.. I like playing cards that interact with each other directly.

Comment: This could be a much better question if it asked for ways to search for cards that reference a different card by name. As written it's very unclear what you mean... every card in MTG "interacts" with other cards.

Comment: Clearly the guy who asked the question finds the answer he got useful?  Isn't that enough?  This is stackexchange not wikipedia

Comment: @Affe - It's not quite enough. The idea behind Stackexchange is to create a large set of useful questions and answers that can be useful to people. Not that this is necessarily the case here, but if a question is only useful to the person who asked it, it is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @GendoIkari it's useful to anyone who wants to build a deck using cards referencing eachother directly by name.... on Stack Overflow just because someone asks a question about php doesn't mean its only useful to that person.. people who only code in java don't downvote it or put it on hold.

Comment: Just to clarify, I downvoted because I do not find the question useful. I voted to close (put on hold) because I think the question is too broad.

Comment: I've edited and voted to reopen, given that how to search for something is a perfectly fine question and the OP was clearly interested in it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Creating a search query that returns all cards that reference other cards, without having false positives or false negatives is difficult, but I will show the kinds of things to search for to find some of them. All of these queries are using [MagicCards.info](http://magiccards.info/)

> o:named

This is the most basic one, it searches for all cards with "named" in their card text. This generates a lot of false positives, mostly cards that refer to themselves like [Accumulated Knowledge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Accumulated%20Knowledge), cards that have someone name a card like [Booby Trap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Booby%20Trap), or ones that create tokens with names like [Boris Devilboon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boris%20Devilboon).

This part is always required, and will be left out of future queries for brevity.

> -o:~

This removes any cards that have their own name in the text box. This creates some false negatives from things like [Diligent Farmhand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Diligent%20Farmhand), but also removes a large number of false positives (It removes about 100 cards from the results).

> -o:"name a card"

This removes any cards that have the text "name a card" in the text box. I don't think this creates any false negatives, but doesn't remove that many cards from the result (less than 20).

> -o:"token named"

This removes any cards that have the text "token named" in their text box. Note that this only removes things with vanilla tokens (ie ones with no abilities), ones that have abilities like [Wirefly Hive](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wirefly%20Hive) will still show up. It also removes the [Helm of Kaldra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20Kaldra) since it produces a Kaldra token.

Combining all of these into (with -is:silver-bordered to remove Un-cards)

> [o:named  -o:~ -o:"name a card" -o:"names a card" -o:"token named" -is:silver-bordered](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3Anamed+-o%3A%7E+-o%3A%22name+a+card%22+-o%3A%22names+a+card%22+-o%3A%22token+named%22+-is%3Asilver-bordered)

We get a list of 18 cards, 3 are false positives, and several cards like the [Helm of Kaldra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20Kaldra) that don't show up, but it gives you a starting place to work from.

- The Unspeakable

  - [Sift Through Sands](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sift%20Through%20Sands)
  - [Peer Through Depths](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Peer%20Through%20Depths)
  - [Reach Through Mists](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reach%20Through%20Mists)
  - [The Unspeakable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Unspeakable)
- Kaldra

  - [Helm of Kaldra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20Kaldra)
  - [Shield of Kaldra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shield%20of%20Kaldra)
  - [Sword of Kaldra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sword%20of%20Kaldra)
- Nissa

  - [Nissa Revane](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nissa%20Revane)
  - [Nissa's Chosen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=185699)
- Empire Artifacts

  - [Crown of Empires](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crown%20of%20Empires)
  - [Scepter of Empires](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scepter%20of%20Empires)
  - [Throne of Empires](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Throne%20of%20Empires)
- Spiders

  - [Arachnus Spinner](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arachnus%20Spinner)
  - [Arachnus Web](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arachnus%20Web)
- Scion of Darkness

  - [Dark Supplicant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Supplicant)
  - [Scion of Darkness](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20Darkness)
- Spirit of Night

  - [Urborg Panther](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urborg%20Panther)
  - [Feral Shadow](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Feral%20Shadow)
  - [Breathstealer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Breathstealer)
  - [Spirit of the Night](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spirit%20of%20the%20Night)
- Viashivan Dragon

  - [Kyscu Drake](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kyscu%20Drake)
  - [Spitting Drake](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spitting%20Drake)
  - [Viashivan Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Viashivan%20Dragon)
- Alternate Timeline Weapon-makers

  - [Renowned Weaponsmith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Renowned%20Weaponsmith)
  - [Heart-Piercer Bow](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heart-Piercer%20Bow)
  - [Vial of Dragonfire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vial%20of%20Dragonfire)
- Bant Angel

  - [Angels' Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175141)
  - [Empyrial Archangel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Empyrial%20Archangel)
- Esper Sphinx

  - [Sphinx's Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175242)
  - [Sphinx Sovereign](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sphinx%20Sovereign)
- Grixis Demon

  - [Demon's Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175243)
  - [Prince of Thralls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prince%20of%20Thralls)
- Jund Dragon

  - [Dragon's Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175239)
  - [Hellkite Overlord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hellkite%20Overlord)
- Naya Beast

  - [Behemoth's Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=175263)
  - [Godsire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Godsire)
- Bursts

  - [Muscle Burst](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muscle%20Burst)
  - [Diligent Farmhand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Diligent%20Farmhand)
  - [Flame Burst](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flame%20Burst)
  - [Pardic Firecat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pardic%20Firecat)

Comment: This is a neat list, but ultimately not very helpful... is it possible to list criteria that can be used to search for such cards? (I have no idea if Gatherer has any way of searching for this).

Comment: @GendoIkari There isn't really any way to easily search for them. The best I can think of is having the Rules Test contains 'named', but that ends up with a lot of false positives.

Comment: You forgot urzatron :)

Comment: @Affe Technically the Urzatron don't care about card names, that tracks card types.

Comment: You can do this relatively easy if you just download one of the copies of the oracle database that you can easily find. I found these plus a handful more with a quick python script. (I excluded things like the Bursts, though, because if you count cards that refer to themselves there are a lot more.)

Comment: @jefromi The cards listed with three bursts refer to the other cards, the bursts, by name. Not just referring to themselves.

Comment: @GendoIkari Right, duh.

Comment: @diego Maybe I don't understand what you mean but AFAIK the urzatron refers to Urza's Mine, Tower and Powerplant which all reference eachother by name. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @AndreasHüttig They do not reference each other by name. Urza's Mine says "If you control an Urza's Power-Plant and an Urza's Tower" if it referenced the others by name it would say "If you control a land named Urza's Power Plant and a land named Urza's Tower". With the way it is written, you could copy the mine with Sakashima (assuming the mine because a creature somehow) and remove the mine from the battlefield and still have your Tower and Power Plant tap for the additional mana. Because while Sakashima doesn't have the name Urza's Mine it still has the subtypes Urza's and Mine.

Comment: Also if you look at Urza's Power Plant, the cards that reference it use Urza's Power-Plant when that is not the name of the card, but rather its subtype

Comment: I did a quick google before and only found the old cards (yes, I'm that old and I've not played magic a lot since the redesign for 8th/Mirrodin in 2003). The new cards (which I googled after not being able to match your explanation to my expectation of the card you were refering to) say "Land - Urzas Mine" as card type.

Thanks for a flawed but still helpful answer :)

Comment: @AndreasHüttig If you are ever wondering what the official text of a card is you can check [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx), which contains the official text of any card (and the original text so you can see if it's changed)

Answer (score 4):

The search engine [mtg.wtf](https://mtg.wtf/) uses the full list of card names to generate the `related:` parameter, so searching for [`related:*`](https://mtg.wtf/card?q=related%3A*) on mtg.wtf also shows some cards that are missing in the other answer:

- Ajani's Aid refers to Ajani, Valiant Protector
- Gideon's Resolve refers to Gideon, Martial Paragon
- Kookus refers to Keeper of Kookus
- Liberating Combustion refers to Chandra, Pyrogenius
- Liu Bei, Lord of Shu refers to Guan Yu, Sainted Warrior and Zhang Fei, Fierce Warrior
- Marauding Maulhorn refers to Advocate of the Beast
- Peacekeeper Avatar refers to Arrest
- Pious Kitsune refers to Eight-and-a-Half-Tails
- Rohgahh of Kher Keep refers to Kobolds of Kher Keep
- Walker of the Wastes refers to Wastes

Comment: At least in this case mtg.wtf's search engine is much better, nice answer.